# Understanding the definition of omnibus tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnibus_test)

> Omnibus tests ... test whether **the explained variance** in a set of
>   data is significantly greater than **the unexplained variance**,
>   overall.
>
> ...
>
> Omnibus test as a statistical test is implemented on an overall
>   hypothesis that tends to find general significance between parameters'
>   variance, while examining parameters of the same type, such as:
>   Hypotheses regarding equality vs. inequality between k expectancies
>   $µ_1=µ_2=…=µ_k$ vs. $µ_1≠µ_2≠...≠ µ_k$ in Analysis Of Variance(ANOVA)
>   ;

I was wondering what it means by a variance  being explained or unexplained?

How shall I understand what an Omnibus test is?

What is a set that is not omnibus?

Thanks and regards!

---

Added: I was wondering if the following likelihood ratio test for the global null is an omnibus test, quoted from Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference?

[image]

...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was wondering what it means by a variance being explained or
>   unexplained?

It the context of ANOVA it means the variance "explained" by group membership and the variance that remains unexplained.  To understand this in detail you have to really look at the equations.  I'll try to explain it anyway without introducing too many equations.  In the case of a one-way ANOVA each value observed can be thought of as being composed of three sources of variance, the grand mean, the group mean deviation from the grand mean, and error... $x = \bar{\bar{x}} + (\bar{\bar{x}} - \bar{x}_k) + e$.  If you assume there are no group differences then all $\bar{x}_k = \bar{\bar{x}}$ therefore, by estimating $\bar{x}_k$ you haven't 'explained' very little or no extra variance.  Imagine instead that the null hypothesis is false and you go ahead and estimated the deviations of the group means from the grand means.  If you then adjust each score by the deviation of the group to which it belongs and then recalculated the variance of the scores, you will find that the variance is smaller than it was before.  That reduction in variance is the variance that you 'explained' by estimating means for each group.

> How shall I understand what an omnibus test is?

Tests are referred to as omnibus if after rejecting the null hypothesis you do not know where the differences assessed by the statistical test are.  In the case of F tests they are omnibus when there is more than one df in the numerator (3 or more groups) it is omnibus.  In the case of Chi-square tests, when there is more than one df it is omnibus.

> What is a set that is not omnibus?

Comparisons between two groups such as those that happen in the cases detailed above F with 1 df in the numerator and Chi Square with 1 df.

Comment: Thanks, Russell!  In [Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xMBk7.png), is the likelihood ratio test for the global null an omnibus test?

Comment: To be honest my eyes start to glaze over when I see that much greek notation, especially if I haven't eased into getting used to whatever specific notation conventions the author is using.  The title of the test itself certainly sounds omnibus.

Comment: I did a quick google search and it looks like this procedure is used to test an overall logistic regression model or to compare two models.  As before, it should yield an F or Chi-square test statistic.  The rules mentioned above still hold.  If the df is > 1 then you are testing one or more comparisons units of interest (in anova this would be $\bar{x}_1 = \bar{\bar{x}}, \bar{x}_2 = \bar{\bar{x}}, ..., \bar{x}_k = \bar{\bar{x}}$ and in the regression framework it is $b_0 = 0, b_1 = 0, ..., b_k = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, Russell! I added more context to the quote, and hope that it may be clearer. It is a general approach, since it only involves likelihood ratio test (LRT) and Union-intersection test (UIT).

Comment: I posted it as [a new question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59941/is-the-likelihood-ratio-test-for-the-global-null-considered-to-be-an-omnibus-tes).

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't look for a rigorous definition of omnibus test. It seems typically used for overall tests with wide scope, packing several tests into one.

Other terms used with similar import are portmanteau statistic and factotum statistic.

Over a century or more, there have been all sorts of fashions over terminology, including statisticians reaching for their Latin and Greek (ancillary, histogram, chi-square, heteroscedasticity), statisticians reaching for their thesaurus (as here), statisticians naming tests after their teachers or friends, ideally in pairs (Mann-Whitney, Kruskal-Wallis), and statisticians eager to show off their homespun sides (jackknife, bootstrap). Even the words that look familiar had to be invented (average, mode, regression).

Comment: Thanks! How can I tell if a test is omnibus or not?

Comment: Count the equals signs, sometimes. The more there are, the more omnibus-like. However, I guess scope is the important thing. But I don't think there is consistency on this. Often names, as here, are just sticky labels: you can peel them off, or they drop off, and nothing's different underneath. I don't think there's an idea lurking there except that of an overarching test. You might find a definition lurking somewhere. This is just my impression: corrections and rebuttals may follow.

Comment: Is an omnibus test contrasted to multiple comparisons?

Comment: Can be. Depends what you mean by multiple comparisons. Do you mean comparing individual means after anova (classical, narrow sense) or any post hoc specific comparison once a model is fitted? I don't see that the idea is confined to anova or linear models set-ups. If you want some definitions, you may need to define some terms yourself first.

Comment: I saw omnibus test when reading about [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons). The link has what multiple comparisons is trying to do.

Comment: No, it is the Wikipedia article on multiple comparisons. It seems to range from very clear and reasonable statements to unwarranted emphasis on what follows anova, but I have only skimmed it.