# Is the likelihood ratio test for the global null considered to be an omnibus test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

Continue from my [last question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59891/1005) about an omnibus test. When the (global) null is the intersection of several individual nulls, I was wondering if the likelihood ratio test for the global null is considered to be an omnibus test. For more details, I quote from Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference:

[image]

...

[image]

Thanks and regards!

Comment: If you compare the a certain model with the *null model* using a likelihood ratio test (LRT), the answer is **yes**, it is an omnibus test. See also [this reference](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~dasgupta/testing.pdf) (page 319).

Comment: @COOLSerdash:Thanks! Has DasGupta defined omnibus test somewhere before in other notes?

Comment: I can't find any other reference from DasGupta, but a quick Google Books search revealed the following [results](https://www.google.ch/#q=%22omnibus+test%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=g3afUa39Ic-WhQf-5ICoDw&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAg&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.ZWU&fp=51c43a856757b978&biw=1920&bih=955). Maybe you'll find further references there.